# Magma vs. Plasma

Tags: linear-algebra, lapack, blas, gpu

I'm having a difficult time understanding the difference between the linear algebra packages [MAGMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/) and [PLASMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/plasma/index.html) from just a quick glance. It looks like MAGMA is oriented towards GPU's and vector coprocessors, while PLASMA is oriented towards a vanilla multicore system. But I'd appreciate an explanation comparing them, and what they do differently from BLAS/LAPACK/ScaLAPACK.

Comment: Why did you use a comment instead of submitting an answer below?

Comment: I emailed the PLASMA/MAGMA developers, and their current preference is that questions about the distributions be directed to their forums: [MAGMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/forum/viewforum.php?f=2)
,[PLASMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/plasma/forum/viewforum.php?f=2), [LAPACK](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/).

Comment: Or they could just add a simple blurb on each of the websites so people aren't tempted to ask their favorite, easily searchable computational scientist forum instead.

Comment: Well, you know what my opinion on that would be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/news_pub/submissions/plasma-scidac09.pdf) or the PLASMA README. LAPACK is serial and parallelism enters only via multi threaded BLAS3. ScaLAPACK is for distributed memory machines and requires BLACS/MPI. PLASMA targets shared memory parallelism on multicore machines.